# unobtrusive js in rails app not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to as such:

```
<%= link_to "Load More", comments_feed_path(@post.id), :id => 'my-link', :remote => true %>
```

and this in the application.js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#my-link').bind('click', function() {
        alert('Hooray!');

       //event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
      });
});
```

yet nothing happens. If I do this instead it works as expected, but I would rather use unobtrusive js...

```
<%= link_to "Load More", comments_feed_path(@story.id), :id => 'my-link', :onclick => "test()", :remote => true%>
```

application.js:

```
function test(){
    alert('test');
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: What's the version of jquery? Not sure this is an issue, but try using preferred `on` method. `$(el).on('click', handler);`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a usual turbolinks issue. Turbolinks is the gem, by default included in rails, that prevents common part of the page from being loaded on each request. The most common part that it prevents from being reloaded is a header, including all the javascript definitions. That means, that your `$(document).ready` callback is only executed for the initial page of your application.

To fix it, you need to change `$(document).ready` to:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
```

Have a read of documentation: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Comment: unfortunately this did not seem to fix the problem.  I don't see any errors in the console either.

Comment: @user2884789 - Could you check what version of turbolinks are you using in your Gemfile?